# sudo -s source /home/UserName/.bashrc

Tags: debian, sudo, bashrc

On my GNU/Linux Debian 9, I would like to run:

```
sudo -s source /home/UserName/.bashrc
```

Respectively I would like to define an alias like that one, let's name it `su2`.

<strike>I can't manage to run a command like that.</strike>

The command runs successfully, but not as to my expectations.

Invoking it does not seemingly do anything, not even make me root.

I am confused as to why that is.

So what I want it to do:

1. root me like:

   ```
   sudo -s
   ```
2. source my **personal** bashrc and aliases like:

   ```
   source /home/UserName/.bashrc
   source /home/UserName/.bash_aliases
   ```

That's all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`source` is a shell built-in, so you can’t run it *via* `sudo`. The following should work:

```
sudo bash --rcfile /home/UserName/.bashrc
```

`.bash_aliases` is typically processed by `.bashrc` (it’s not supported by Bash by default), with something like

```
if [ -f ~/.bash_aliases ]; then . ~/.bash_aliases; fi
```

To handle your aliases correctly, you can replace this with

```
if [ -f /home/UserName/.bash_aliases ]; then . /home/UserName/.bash_aliases; fi
```

Comment: Doesn’t your `.bashrc` take care of that?

Comment: ^If not just use `&&` or `;` e.g `sudo bash --rcfile /home/UserName/.bashrc ; sudo bash --rcfile /home/UserName/.bash_aliases`

Comment: @Hunter think about that, it can’t work...

Comment: @Vlastimil the simplest solution there is for you to change that in your `.bashrc`.